# Bash - How to find line from one file as a part of a line from another file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, find

I ve got two files:

1.txt

```
/stackoverflow.com/questions
/stackoverflow.com/reports
/stackoverflow.com/answers
```

2.txt

```
/stackoverflow.com/questions/18959800/grep-each-line-from-a-file-in-another-file
/stackoverflow.com/answers/18984800/grep-each-line-from
/stackoverflow.com/questions/20559800/line-from-a-file-in-another-file
/stackoverflow.com/ask/9959800/file-in-another-file-second_line
```

If line from 1.txt is a part of lines from 2.txt print this line.
If a line from 2.txt are not matched print this lines.

I would like to get as an output.txt file like this:

output.txt:

```
/stackoverflow.com/questions/
/stackoverflow.com/reports/
/stackoverflow.com/answers/
/stackoverflow.com/ask/9959800/file-in-another-file-second_line
```

it is posible to have all lines in one file:

```
/stackoverflow.com/questions
/stackoverflow.com/reports
/stackoverflow.com/answers
/stackoverflow.com/questions/18959800/grep-each-line-from-a-file-in-another-file
/stackoverflow.com/answers/18984800/grep-each-line-from
/stackoverflow.com/questions/20559800/line-from-a-file-in-another-file 
/stackoverflow.com/ask/9959800/file-in-another-file-second_line
```

Comment: Are you sure about that `output.txt`? If so, please explain the logic better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As OP have added that lines from previous Input_file too needed so edited solution as follows too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} {for(i in a){if(match($0,a[i])){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);b[i]=i;next}};print;} END{for(k in a){if(b[k]==""){print a[k]}}}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]=$0;
  next}
{
  for(i in a){
    if(match($0,a[i])){
      print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
      b[i]=i;
      next}};
    print}
END{
  for(k in a){
    if(b[k]==""){
      print a[k]}}
}
' 1.txt 2.txt
```

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} {for(i in a){if(match($0,a[i])){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);next}};print}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

Comment: looks good, but one case is not meet, my bad i have no mentioned it

If any line from 1.txt is not meet in 2.txt , shuold be printed too

Comment: @MaciejNowak, kindly check my EDIT solution and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: YES, you were help me, thank U.
but there was a small problem with repeated lines, but
**sort -u** solved it.

Comment: You can accept his answer, he worked hard and helped you.